# Android Action bar shadow

Tags: android-actionbar

I need to do the actionbar like the below image, I have marked the shadow area 
[image]

Here can see the small shadow so how can I add this shadow to the action bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the elevation in your toolbar.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_color"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>

I used this but did not get the shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Android 5.0 or support library, you should use setElevation

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(2);
```

If you still using ActionBarSherlock, you should change your theme style like this:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">ANY_NUMBER</item>
</style>
```